# standard way to discover gRPC service

Tags: grpc

What is the standard way for a remote client to discover available services on gRPC server? I know there is something called gRPC reflection. But how do we use it? I am looking for language agnostic solution (provided gRPC support)

Comment: What gRPC language are you using?  For Java, there is a special package that contains a Server Reflection "service", but other languages include it elsewhere.

Comment: Are you wanting to do the reflection from a random language at runtime, do the reflection as part of development, or simply from something like the command line?

Answer (score 5):

I see that my answer can be useless looking at the date of the question.

As far as I understand browsing log files and deploying `reflection` feature, a grpc client sends POST request  `/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo` using `HTTP/2.0` protocol to grpc server to receive the list of exposed services and their methods, for instance:

```
$ grpcurl --plaintext host:8000 list
grservices.diagnostic
$ ~/gopath/bin/grpcurl --plaintext host:8000 list grservices.diagnostic
GetDateTime
GetTimeZones
```

Log:

```
"POST /grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo HTTP/2.0"
"POST /grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/ServerReflectionInfo HTTP/2.0"
```